# How to display text in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to display text in pygame. I have managed to display it fine in the main loop, but then in the die() function, it doesn't appear.

```
def die():

    while True:
        deadText = text.render("You Died",1,red)
        gameDisplay.blit(deadText,(500,100))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All functions draw in buffer and you have to send buffer to VideoCard which will display to screen.

You need `pygame.display.flip()` or `pygame.display.update()` for this.

Comment: @CalebShaw, if this answer has solved your problem, please consider upvoting and accepting it for visibility. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers